# Compare lists - delete list where id = id and date > date

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists

```
[['Id', 'fname', 'lname', 'gender', 'startdate'],
['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995'],
['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/1995']]
```

i would like to delete duplicate lists where ID == ID AND StartDate < StartDate. 
Leaving the lists with unique ids that have the most recent startdate.

```
[['Id', 'fname', 'lname', 'gender', 'startdate'],
['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995']]
```

Any help would be great

Comment: This should be a list of dicts

Answer (score 4):

Stuff rows into dictionary by ID after sorting them in date order. The only thing you have to do yourself is to remove the header before using this.

```
import time

data = [['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995'],
['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/1995']]

data = sorted(data, key=lambda x:time.strptime(x[4], '%m/%d/%Y'))   # sort data in ascending date order

keys = [x[0] for x in data]
print keys

d = dict(zip(keys,data))                 # add to dictionary ... most recent values overwrite older ones

print d.values()
```

Generates output:

```
[['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'], ['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995']]
```

Comment: seems like a great way to remove duplicates but the question has more criteria for deletion that duplicate id. thanks

Comment: This addresses the data requirement as well ... anything else I missed?

Comment: Did you remove the first row of headers? And if so ... can you post the actual date it fails with?

Comment: my apologizes. yes, after removing the header it works great! thanks a lot for you help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Maria Zverina's, but a bit more structured:

```
import time

data = [
    ['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
    ['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995'],
    ['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/1995']
]

# sort by date, ascending
data.sort(key=lambda d: time.strptime(d[4], "%m/%d/%Y"))

# load into a dict, key on ID, later data overwrites earlier
latest = dict((d[0], d) for d in data)

# return to list, sorted by ID
data = sorted(latest.itervalues(), key=lambda d: int(d[0]))
```

returns

```
# most recent data for each ID, sorted by ID:
[
    ['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
    ['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. I just put the keys into a set as I find them. The `orig` variable contains the original list of list and `res` is list of list with duplicate removed.

```
mod_set  = set()
res = list()
for x in orig:
    if x[0] not in mod_set:
            res.append(x)
            mod_set.add(x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script to do what you want:

```
import time

mylist = [['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'],
['101', 'Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995'],
['100', 'John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/1995']]

dict = {} 
for sublist in mylist: 
   id,fname,lname,gender,startdate = sublist 
   if not id in dict: 
      dict[id] = [fname,lname,gender,startdate] 
   else: 
      olddate = dict[id][3] 
      if time.strptime(startdate,'%d/%m/%Y') > time.strptime(olddate,'%d/%m/%Y'): 
         dict[id] = [fname,lname,gender,startdate] 

print dict

Output: {'100': ['John', 'Jackson', 'M', '08/09/2000'], '101': ['Jenny', 'Hobbs', 'F', '01/13/1995']}
```

At the end `dict` will contain unique IDs pointing to the most recent records.